# Is it possible to use android specific functions like in-app purchase using PlayN?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, playn

I am interested in PlayN. But I am not sure if I can use android specific functions like in-app purchase using PlayN.

Comment: I saw this page: http://playn-2011.appspot.com/slides/index.html#47 . But I am not sure if this is same as android in app purchase.